# sp_repladdcolumn - is it possible to supply a list of Publications to add this column on?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

### Scenario

We have an existing table in 3 different publications (going to 3 different subscribers), 1 of those publications does not publish all columns.

All of these are transactional pull subscriptions.

I now need to add some more columns onto this table and we want to add them on to just the first two publications.  However from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189464.aspx):

> [ @publication_to_add =] 'publication_to_add' Is the name of the
>   publication to which the new column is added. publication_to_add is
>   nvarchar(4000), with a default of ALL. If ALL, then all publications
>   containing this table are affected. If publication_to_add is
>   specified, then only this publication has the new column added.

which implies that it you expects it to specify **1** publication or **ALL** publications.

A sample table/publication detail to help demonstrate the issue:

**Table sample**

```
[MyTable] (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    myName varchar(50) NULL,
    myDOB datetime,
    myJob varchar(100),
    mySpouseID int )
```

**Publication/Subscriber sample**

```
[InternalPublication] All fields, sent to InternalAdmin system
[Reporting] All fields, sent to Reporting/Datawarehouse system
[External] sent to External accessable system, fields sent:
    (ID, myName, myDOB)
```

### Question

How do I add on:

```
[myMarriageDate] datetime NULL,
[myDivorceDate] datetime NULL
```

and have it **only** added to the publications **[InternalPublication]** and **[Reporting]**?

*Note: sample is a made up one to protect the innocent*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sp_repladdcolumn is deprecated unless you have SQL2000 subscribers, you should use the Replicate Schema changes option on the publication. Assuming you have that set to No, I guess you could still use the sp_repladdcolumn, and if you look at the source for the proc, it looks like it has handling for accepting a comma separated list of publications, ***but using it is venturing into undocumented handling of a deprecated procedure...i.e. no guarantees.***

```
sp_repladdcolumn  @source_object =  'fooTable',  
                  @column =  'fooNewColumn',  
                  @typetext =  'int' ,  
                  @publication_to_add =  '[pub1],[pub2]'
```

EDIT: Publication names need to be in `[]` for it to work as in the code of **sp_repladdcolumns** it has:

```
select p.name, a.name, a.pubid from dbo.sysmergepublications p, dbo.sysmergearticles a   
where p.pubid=a.pubid and a.objid=@objid and p.snapshot_ready=0 
     and (p.name like @publication_to_add 
         or charindex('[' + p.name + ']', @publication_to_add)>0)
```

Comment: Thanks @SqlACID, do you know of any examples using the list of publications (a link would be great!)

Comment: @Andrew Updated with sample code

Comment: updated, have looked through the code for sp_repladdcolumn & there are some issues, it looks like if the pub names are in [] then it *should* work

Answer (score 2):

As SqlAcid already pointed, the sp [sp_repladdcolumn is already deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189464%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and shouldn't be used any further. From now on [propagated schema changes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870%28SQL.90%29.aspx) should be used, which is anyway the default line of action.

Instead of propagating some schema changes to only a part of your subscribers, I'd say to remove the current table article from the third subscriber, create a view on the publisher that will contain only a part of the table, using only the needed columns, than add this view as an article to the third publication and not on the first two.

Might be a better solution for future changes, when you will still allow other schema changes to be propagated properly to your all 3 subscribers.

Comment: Thanks @Marian, nice alternative (though I don't have the option of that in this case, I will definitely consider it when it comes up again :-)